# Conversion of numpy 2d array to ENVI binary file through gdal

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, gis, geospatial, gdal

I have SAR CEOS format files which consist of data file, leader file, null volume directory file and volume directory file.

I am reading the data file using gdal ReadAsArray and then I am doing operations on this 2d Array and now I want to save this 2d array as an ENVI binary file.

Kindly guide how to do this in Python 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Find help for Tutorial Website: https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/
- Such as the example of

  ```
  import gdal, ogr, os, osr
  import numpy as np

  def array2raster(newRasterfn,rasterOrigin,pixelWidth,pixelHeight,array):
      cols = array.shape[1]
      rows = array.shape[0]
      originX = rasterOrigin[0]
      originY = rasterOrigin[1]

      driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('ENVI')
      outRaster = driver.Create(newRasterfn, cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
      outRaster.SetGeoTransform((originX, pixelWidth, 0, originY, 0, pixelHeight))
      outband = outRaster.GetRasterBand(1)
      outband.WriteArray(array)
      outRasterSRS = osr.SpatialReference()
      outRasterSRS.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
      outRaster.SetProjection(outRasterSRS.ExportToWkt())
      outband.FlushCache()

  def main(newRasterfn,rasterOrigin,pixelWidth,pixelHeight,array):
      reversed_arr = array[::-1] # reverse array so the tif looks like the array
      array2raster(newRasterfn,rasterOrigin,pixelWidth,pixelHeight,reversed_arr) # convert array to raster

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      rasterOrigin = (-123.25745,45.43013)
      pixelWidth = 10
      pixelHeight = 10
      newRasterfn = 'test.tif'
      array = np.array([[ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                        [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                        [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                        [ 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                        [ 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                        [ 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                        [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                        [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                        [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                        [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])

      main(newRasterfn,rasterOrigin,pixelWidth,pixelHeight,array)
  ```

Comment: You might want to provide some information why we need to "reverse" the array.